# Skip subsequent Actions read for current testcase if any action Fails

Tags: playwright, skip, data-files, playwright-typescript

I have a playwright test with PageObject model(Typescripting) where spec file contains test.describe with For loop to read each actions from a data file and call respective functions defined in separate file.

I got 10+ paths in each data file having 10+ actions for each Path.
Is there a way to skip the subsequent actions for the Path being executed if any action fails.

```
Specfile.ts

test.describe( async () => {
    test.beforeAll(async ({ }) => { const browser = await playwright.chromium.launch({});   };
    testData.forEach((data) => {
       test(data.path , async() => {
         if (action= XXX) {Call Function A}
        if (action=YYY) {Call Function B}
}
}


Datafile.ts

const testData [
{  Path: path1, PathTitile : test1,   Actions [ Action1, Action2, Action3 ]  }
{  Path: path2, PathTitile : test2,  Actions [ Action1, Action2, Action3 ]  }
{  Path: path3, PathTitile : test2,  Actions [ Action1, Action2, Action3 ]  }

]
```

test.skip is skipping the whole datafile and all remaining paths are skipped.

Expectation is to skip pending Actions in the current Path alone and proceed with next Path.

Comment: Just to add, below is the function in spec file which reads data Array with each objecting containing many actions and call functions defined. For this code if test.fail is invoked, its causing all other data objects to be skipped.

data.stepActions.forEach((step) => {
            test(`${data.flowPath} step#${i++}`, async () => {
                    await test.step(`${data.flowPath}` ,async () => { 
                    exitcode= await flow[step.action](step.arg);
                    test.fail(exitcode!=1,'Failing the test');   });   
                }
            );  
        });

Answer (score 0):

To achieve something like this, you will want to conditionally skip your tests. This will need added to your test block (test.describe) if you want entire blocks to be skipped, or to each test individually if you want each one to be skipped independently.

This is all from a quick mock up so tailor to your needs!

In your test, create a boolean variable called something like 'passed', and assign to default of true. Make sure you declare this outside your tests.

`let passed:boolean = true;`

Then, in each test, add something like:

`test.skip(passed===false, 'Test failed. Skipping.');`
At the very beginning of the test. Like:

`test('do stuff', async ({ page}) => { test.skip(passed === false, 'Skipping'); });`

This means each test checks the result variable and skips if it failed previously. All that is left is to add logic to each test that if it meets your desired condition, set `passed` to true. Else, set it to false. That can just be a simple if statement or something more complex. Your test goal will dictate this so I cant write that for you!

As mentioned, this is all just as an idea and im doing this on mobile, so ignore any syntax issues. This should steer you in a good direction!

If you want to keep the test going after failure, but still mark it as failed, look at adding soft assertions which are designed to do just that. Read up on this: https://playwright.dev/docs/test-assertions#soft-assertions

Comment: Thanks  for the details. We are actually trying almost same method and then faced couple of issues.

For reporting purpose, we need to make sure the step which failed to have status of Failed. 
so we added test.fail(); But adding test.skip() on top of fail is not helping out as test.fail() is not even attempting remaining steps of whole data file. 

our aim is to have something like below, Where datafile has 2 Paths of 3 steps each and only Path1.Step2 expected to fail.

Path 1: 
Step 1: Pass
Step 2: Failed
Step 3: Skipped

Path 2:
Step 1: Passed
Step 2: Passed
Step 3: Passed

Comment: If you want continued execution, you dont want to test.fail(), as this will end the test. You will want something like a soft assertion which marks the test as failed but doesnt terminate. See here: https://playwright.dev/docs/test-assertions#soft-assertions. Ill add this to my answer

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding soft assertion, but its failing the step and skipping all the remaining step in the data file..  My data file contains array of data paths and i want to just skip the remaining steps in current Path only..  

                    await test.step(`${data.flowPath}` ,async () => { 
                  { exitcode= await flow[step.action](step.arg);
                            expect.soft(exitcode,"test error").toBe(0);       
            }

Comment: I dont quite understand. If you want to just skip the current iteration, skipping is all you need. If you want to treat each array items paths as independant things to skip as you please, you will need a nested loop, where you loop over array, then loop over that elements paths/actions etc.

Comment: So the Data File has array of data objects with each object having bunch of actions. 
If any action fails, i want to fail that step and skip remaining steps in that dataObject and proceed with execution of next dataObject. 
soft assertion is failing the step, but skipping all the steps in the data file instead of the dataObject being executed. 

For Eg: 1st DataObject has actions like launch a page,, find some product, customize and purchase. 
2nd DataObject has actions like launch the page , find diff product, customize and cancel at the end. etc..

Comment: To achieve that you just need to loop over the dataObject, and add another nested loop to run over the actions for the dataObject iteration as I mentioned. But, the nested loop must be declared INSIDE  the test, meaning it wont create many tests, and all actions will be within one test. So, if you soft assert or skip, this will do what you want. Your issue is your scope here. You havent quite grasped how you have scoped your tests. If you want all actions for each data object to be skipped, looping over them in a single test will let you break out on failure, provided its nested

Comment: @krish19xx did you get this resolved?